# longPointerPress() is never invoked on a lead component

Tags: codenameone

When a component is set as the lead component in a container, its `longPointerPress()` method is never invoked.

Consider the following example:

```
final Button lead = new Button("Lead") {
  @Override
  public void longPointerPress(int x, int y) {
      super.longPointerPress(x, y);
      // Never invoked!!!
      Dialog.show("", "Long pointer press at (" + x + "," + y + ")", "OK", null);
  }};

// --------------------------------
// | Label | Lead | Another label |
// --------------------------------
final Container c = BoxLayout.encloseX(new Label("Label"), lead, new Label("Another label"));
c.setLeadComponent(lead);
```

The `longPointerPress()` is never invoked. However, if I set `c.setLeadComponent(null)`, the long press is invoked. However, I lose out on the lead component notion.

Is this a bug? If not, how can I realize what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this way

Button lead = new Button....

`lead.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (event.isLongEvent()) {
            //do long click event stuff
        }else{
            //do normal click event stuff or blank if nothing to do
        }
    }`

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I think I tried this earlier and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a a bug it's a fix. This works:

```
Form hi = new Form("LongPress", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
hi.add(new MultiButton("Long Press") {
    @Override
    public void longPointerPress(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("Long press");
    }
});
```

The long pointer press is invoked on the lead `Container`.

Comment: 1. Why is this considered a fix? I would expect that once there's a lead component, it will also capture the long press.

Comment: 2. The solution you propose would work for MultiButtons but what about cases like mine where a MultiButton is not sufficient/used? PS: The example I sketched was a simplified case; I have a more complex UI that doesn't fit in the MultiButton constraints.

Comment: It would work for every lead component. Just override the longPress in the parent container not in the component itself.

Comment: For me this wasn't picking it. I had to override at form level